# Creating simple constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am trying to write a constructor that when `increment` is called it outputs this:

```
var increment = new Increment();
alert(increment); // 1
alert(increment); // 2
alert(increment + increment); // 7
```

I am trying to go this way:

```
var increment = 0;
function Increment(increment){
    increment += 1;
};
```

But the alerts outputs `[object object]`.

Any idea?

EDIT: apparently I am not allowed to touch the existing code, as the cuestion of this exercise is: «Create a constructor whose instances will return the incremented number»

Comment: Sure, what did you expect? You have specifically set `increment = new Increment()`, that way `increment` will get an object reference assigned to it.

Comment: Since your real code probably won't just do an `alert` but use that value in other ways, trying to get this kind of automagic to work is not really possible (i.e. something that returns a different number whenever it's "accessed"; because "being accessed" isn't really a thing in Javascript). At the very least you'd have to make it something like `incrementor.next()` to be able to use it productively in code.

Comment: Why use a constructor at all? Just use a closure...

Comment: With that first snippet, you're redefining `increment` from the number 0 to an instance of `Increment`, which is an object.

Comment: It is an exercise I was given. The exact question was «Create a constructor whose instances will return the incremented number», and with the first code. I am trying to solve it, but really don't understand it!

Comment: Sounds like the person who wrote the exercise doesn't understand JS very well... (well IMO)

Comment: @evolutionxbox, the person understand JS ;-)

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm just being mean... not in a happy mood today.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, i am sorry for you.

Comment: @NinaScholz me too. I'd still prefer a closure over a constructor, but that's just me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ususally, you need a method for incrementing the value and you need to call it.

```js
function Increment(value) {
    this.value = value || 0;
    this.inc = function () { return ++this.value; };
}

var incrementor = new Increment;

console.log(incrementor.inc()); // 1
console.log(incrementor.inc()); // 2
console.log(incrementor.inc() + incrementor.inc()); // 7
```

But you could take a constructor and implement a `toString` function for getting a primitive value.

This solution is not advisable, but it works for educational use. (It does not work with `console.log` here, because it need an expecting environment for a primitive value.)

```js
function Increment(value) {
    value = value || 0;
    this.toString = function () { return ++value; };
}

var increment = new Increment;

alert(increment); // 1
alert(increment); // 2
console.log(increment + increment); // 7
```

Comment: Thanks Nina! Apparently in this exercise I am now allowed to touch the existing code, because the precise question was «Create a constructor whose instances will return the incremented number».

Comment: YYYEah @nina, this is what I was looking for. Not a very complicated code, but a bit tricky… :)

Comment: @Nikita I hope you reference this answer in your submission. I don't want you getting in trouble for plagarism.

Comment: Once you learn it is not plagiarism anymore! The problem is to understand it and fix it, and use it in another contexts…

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that are conceptually wrong here, to keep it simple what you could do is:

```
 function Increment(){
    this.value = 0;
 }
 Increment.prototype.increase = function(){this.value++}
 Increment.prototype.getValue = function(){return this.value}

 let incrementInstance = new Increment();
 incrementInstance.increase();
 console.log(incrementInstance.getValue())
```

Basically what you need to do is to create an instance of Increment and then change the value for it

Comment: Thanks Santiago. I was thinking about something similar, but apparently I should touch the existing code. I think the question is quite weird.

Comment: No problem, does it makes sense why your approach is not the right one? You are creating instances of a constructor without properties

Comment: Yes yes, now I have this clear. I have to work with the properties, and maybe store a function inside the object to work with `this` :)

Comment: that's not actually correct, for instance my code does a good use of memory and you should use that (prototype methods instead of methods inside contructor), while the one you marked as correct will create a new function every time you call new Increment.

Comment: Hm, you are in reason; I am new in Javascript, and I can't recognize when something is efficient or not. 
Anyway, as I wasn't able to touch the existing code, and Nina edited her answer giving now a perfect solution, I will leave her response as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Increment(initial){
 this.value = initial
}

Increment.prototype = {
 constructor: Increment,
 inc: function(){
  return ++this.value;
 }
}

increment = new Increment(0);

alert(increment.inc() + increment.inc());
```